# Where exactly does doctrine need PEAR Installer and Pear Package?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, pear

I'm trying to install this ORM library,

but I see it requires PEAR Installer and Pear Package,where are they used?

Comment: I dont recall PEAR being required... What version are you trying to install?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it's required, i think it's rather a way to install it.

from http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/nl/getting-started

"Currently it is possible to install Doctrine four different ways that are listed below:

```
* SVN (subversion)
* SVN externals
* PEAR Installer
* Download PEAR Package"
```

Comment: Indeed PEAR is not required. You can download the Doctrine library directly from the website and just put `Doctrine.php` and the `Doctrine` folder in your include / autoload path.

Comment: PEAR is usually the better way to install libraries/packages as it makes upgrading and rolling back to different versions hassle-free and also works out interdependencies much like apt or rpm does.
It seems though that doctrine's pear channel is not working at the moment.

my slides from a talk I gave ( http://talks.php.net/show/ossbarcamp2009/5 ) have some info on the subject.